# VML nested image backgrounds for Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, vml, inky

Is it possible to have nested background images using the technique of vml `v:rect` and `v:fill` ? It seems like the nested v:fill will also try to fill the first declared `v:rect` and this is completely messing up my layout

Example of what I'm trying to achieve (using the inky templating language by foundation)

```
<!-- Top level BG -->
<td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="120" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:120px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <!-- Nested BG -->
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:120px;">
          <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
          <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->
            <div>

            </div>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->

      </columns>
    </row>
      <columns>
        <!-- Nested BG -->
        <!-- ... -->
      </columns>
    </row>
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue currently, according to my investigation result, it is grammaly illegal, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.vml.rectangle?view=openxml-2.8.1#remarks), it is not listed in its child elements table